# Statistics question relating to approximating distributions

Tags: statistics

The percentage of defective articles produced by a machine is 8%. Use a suitable
approximation and calculate:
a) The probability that in a random sample of 20 articles, more than 13 will be defective.

Remember to state all the conditions that need to be satisfied in order to use an
appropriate approximation.

So this is a question for an assignment I have and I'm not sure how exactly to approach this? So this seems like a binomial distribution to me so like X is binomial with n=13 and p=0.08 for the first part but since I'm trying to find a range I guess I have to approximate this to a continuous distribution..? Could someone maybe help with this? And in the end am I just trying to find P(13<X<20)?

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [here](/help/notation), [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: A thumb rule for using clt is $n\cdot p \cdot (1-p)>9$. Is this condition satisfied?

Comment: That does not seem to be satisfied but are you sure I need to use CLT here? I thought I just have to use some other approximation but I'm just not sure exactly which.

Comment: @TomAdurite Which  other approximations do you know?

Comment: Well I know binomial to poisson, binomial to normal, would binomial to normal possibly be the correct option here?

Comment: @TomAdurite  Yes, but as I said you have to satisfy some conditons. Another thumb rule is $n\cdot p\geq10$ and $n\cdot (1-p)\geq 10$. Then you can apply the Moivre–Laplace theorem, which is a special case of the clt.